# How to convert array to object and assign value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have array value and object for data mapping. reduce method is not working for object mapping, here is sample data.

the array value is

```
let array = [ "payload", "offer", "application_id" ]
```

object value is

```
let data = {
                organization_id: 4002400004,
                organization_name: 'Velocity Global Integration Sandbox',
                action: 'offer_updated',
                payload: {
                    offer: {
                        id: 4524843004,
                        application_id: 31948577004,
                        user_id: 4123647004,
                        version: 1,
                        sent_on: null,
                        resolved_at: '2022-05-19T06:21:25.084Z',
                        start_date: '2022-05-17',
                        notes: null,
                        job_id: 4298940004,
                        offer_status: 'Accepted'
                    },
                    "resume": {
                        name: "manikandan"
                    }
                }
            }
```

need to form new object with the response

```
let payload = {
    offer: {
        application_id: 343645656
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible there is an error in your "what you want" object? The `application_id` seems unrelated to the object above, should it be `31948577004`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I usually avoid recommending the usage of `eval`, this specific case seems to be a valid use-case for `eval`. You can simply extract the first item of the array as a variable name and extract the subsequent array items as levels:

```js
let array = [ "payload", "offer", "application_id" ]

let data = {
                organization_id: 4002400004,
                organization_name: 'Velocity Global Integration Sandbox',
                action: 'offer_updated',
                payload: {
                    offer: {
                        id: 4524843004,
                        application_id: 31948577004,
                        user_id: 4123647004,
                        version: 1,
                        sent_on: null,
                        resolved_at: '2022-05-19T06:21:25.084Z',
                        start_date: '2022-05-17',
                        notes: null,
                        job_id: 4298940004,
                        offer_status: 'Accepted'
                    },
                    "resume": {
                        name: "manikandan"
                    }
                }
            }

/*let payload = {
    offer: {
        application_id: 343645656
    }
}*/

function getNestedObject(data, array, index) {
    return {[array[index]] : ((index < array.length - 1) ? getNestedObject(data[array[index]], array, index + 1) : data[array[index]])};
}

eval(`var ${array[0]} = getNestedObject(data[array[0]], array, 1)`);
console.log(payload);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.... its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively simple solution using loops.

The idea is to iterate over the array, and always keep a reference to the current object. Since objects are references, modifying `o` will modify the object nested in `ret`.

```js
function pair(array, data) {
  const ret = {};
  let o = ret, d = data;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    const k = array[i];
    o[k] = {};
    o = o[k];
    d = d[k];
  }
  const k = array[array.length - 1];
  o[k] = d[k];
  return ret;
}
```